# Bootstrap 4 anchor links not directing to target

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navigation, anchor

So I have a bootstrap4 one page index page with a navbar that has hyperlinks that jumps to the correct section of the page.
Example: This nav link

goes to the section with id="events:

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#events">Events</a></li>

<div id="events" class="events-container section-container text-left vents px-md-5">
```

I have created a separate contact.php page with the same navbar and links and am linking to sections on the index page from this contact.php page using the following code:

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.php#events">Events</a></li>
```

However, this is not working. Clicking on the link doesn't do anything. All list links will link to the index.php page but not a particular section on that page. Any help or suggestions would be most grateful.

Comment: Are you sure you added some section with id = events? For example <div id="events"> on index.php page?

Comment: Hi, yeah I did add id to all the links to be jumped to. Strangely the navigation list links to all sections with a matching id to the anchor work  on the index.php page. It is only when I am on the contact.php page that I cannot link to the index page sections...very odd. Am using: a href="index.php#events" on the event link on the contact.php page.

Comment: Can you try a direct link? For example: https://mywebsite.com/index.php#events. Is it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours modifying the css and deleting and adding different elements of code-finally found that the problem was the isotope jquery codes-think it was interfering with the anchor links in some way. I removed the isotope.js files from the contact.php page. I am new to javascript and didn't realise how jquery affects other elements. Any hints or suggestions about overriding the isotope affects on anchors much welcome:)

Comment: jQuery _doesn't_ affect elements, but it can be used (as with any JavaScript) to add event listeners to them. There must've been a function or library for dealing with anchor links that you removed. Just loading jQuery or Isotope doesn't change anything as far as behavior.